# Unable to install Thinbgsboard IoT Gateway on windows

Tags: python, thingsboard-gateway

I am trying to apply installation steps for Python on my windows system but I dont know exactly what path should I create for log and config.

I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts>thingsboard-gateway
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\thingsboard-gateway-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('thingsboard-gateway==2.0.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'thingsboard-gateway')()
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\thingsboard_gateway\tb_gateway.py", line 24, in daemon
    TBGatewayService("/etc/thingsboard-gateway/config/tb_gateway.yaml")
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\thingsboard_gateway\gateway\tb_gateway_service.py", line 38, in __init__
    with open(config_file) as config:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/thingsboard-gateway/config/tb_gateway.yaml'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the ThingsBoard Gateway implemented for Debian, CentOS, -based systems. But it doesn't support windows installing (except Docker image). But you can try to replace path to your config file to something like this `c:\\program files\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\thingsboard_gateway\\tb_gateway.py` and try to run it again.